# Opening a .csv file via VBA leads to missing rows

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am using a macro to open a set of selected .csv files, apply the TextToColumns command and then save them as a .xlsx file for further manual processing. One particular .csv file has around 2000 lines in it if I open it manually; when the file is opened via the macro it only contains a total of 1064 lines. Does anyone know what causes this or how I can fix it? Relevant code:

```
Dim iFileSelect As FileDialog
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
Set iFileSelect = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

If iFileSelect.Show = -1 Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each vrtSelectedItem In iFileSelect.SelectedItems
        Workbooks.Open vrtSelectedItem 'After this step the opened csv-file only contains 1064 out of 2000 lines
        'Here a macro is run to convert text to columns
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        SetAttr vrtSelectedItem, vbNormal
        Kill vrtSelectedItem
    Next vrtSelectedItem
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

Set iFileSelect = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, setting the Local parameter to True fixed it, I still don't know how or why so if anyone has any insights I'd appreciate it.
Fixed code:

```
Workbooks.Open vrtSelectedItem, Local:=True
```